# Horizontal UNION ALL in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, union

basically I have two tables - one populated with payment information, one with a payment type and description.

Table 1(not the full table, just the first entries): 
[frs_Payment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCyD3.jpg)

[image]

Table 2: 
frs_PaymentType

[image]

What I'm meant to do is make a query that returns the sum of the amount for each payment type. In other words, my end result should look something like:

```
ptdescription    amountSum
-------------------------
Cash             845.10
Cheque           71.82
Debit            131.67
Credit           203.49
```

(I've worked out the answers)

Getting the ptdescription is easy:

```
SELECT ptdescription
FROM frs_PaymentType
```

And so is getting the amountSum:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS amountSum 
FROM frs_Payment
GROUP BY ptid
```

The question is, how do I combine the two queries into something that I can use in a general case (i.e. if I add another payment type, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use join

```
Select ptdescription,SUM(amount) AS amountSum 
From frs_PaymentType t join frs_Payment p
on t.ptid=p.ptid
GROUP BY t.ptid
```

Comment: Works like a charm! I tried to use join, but for some reason it returned the sum of all the values every time - what did I do wrong?:
`SELECT ptdescription, SUM(amount) AS amountSum
FROM frs_Payment JOIN frs_PaymentType
ON frs_Payment.ptid = frs_Payment.ptid
GROUP BY frs_PaymentType.ptdescription
ORDER BY frs_PaymentType.ptdescription
LIMIT 4`

Comment: it is illegal to use like this wrt standard SQL92. Please refer [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)

Comment: Basically I had to assign a name to the joined tables? Thank you for the quick reply!

Comment: Ya and you changed the group by from ptid to ptdescription. Accept my answer as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows

```
Select ptdescription, SUM(amount) AS amountSum 
From frs_PaymentType t join frs_Payment p
on t.ptid=p.ptid
GROUP BY ptdescription
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This will also take cases where `ptdescription` is not present and would return 'Not Defined' for it.

```
    select 
        case when pt.ptdescription is not null 
        then pt.ptdescription
        else 'Not Defined' as ptdescription, 
        sum(p.amount) AS amountSum 
    from frs_Payment p 
       left join frs_PaymentType pt
    on pt.ptid=p.ptid
    GROUP BY pt.ptdescription
```